# Turning off indent-tabs-mode in Emacs causes malfunction in move-to-column when point is at a newline character

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have problem making `(move-to-column pos t)` work correctly when the cursor is at newline character and I have turned off `indent-tabs-mode`, that is: `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`.

In that case, if for instance the point is at column 0, and there is a newline character at that point ( it is helpful to use `(whitespace-mode)` to see the newline characters ) and I issue the command `(move-to-column 10 t)` the point does not move to column 10. Instead the point moves to column 9.

**Update**

To give an illustration of the problem, consider first the following Emacs buffer

[image]

(the colors are due to `(whitespace-mode)`). The cursor is position at column 0 at the second line of the buffer. There is a newline character just in front of the cursor. I now issue the command `(move-to-column 10 t)` and I get the follwing screen

[image]

Note that the cursor is positioned at column 9 (not at column 10, as it should). If the cursor is not positioned at a newline character and there are no newline characters at the next 10 buffer positions `move-to-column` works as expected. For instance, consider the following case

[image]

Notice that there now is no newline characters at the point (which is at the beginning of the third line in the buffer) and there is no newline characters in the following 10 buffer positions.. If I now issue `(move-to-column 10 t)` I get

[image]

and we see that the point has moved to column 10 as it should..

Comment: `move-to-column` works with screen columns, that means that a character like `^M` occupies two columns. Is that what you are seeing? (If not, please make some kind of drawing of what you see on the screen, what happens, and what you expected.)

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks for looking into this problem. Please see my updated question for more information on the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a problem directly related to `whitespace-mode`. If `whitespace-mode` is turned on I can reproduce it independently of the encoding (ms-dos or unix) if `whitespace-mode` is turned off `move-to-column` shows its expected behaviour. But, I did use `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)`.

Comment: @Tobias Interesting... I have tested without `whitespace-mode` and it still did not work.. Did you use `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`?

Comment: Now, I also tried `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`. `move-to-column` works as expected without `whitespace-mode`. Point moves only up to the end-line character with `whitespace-mode` turned on if the argument indicates that is should move to the character after the end of line. Emacs 24.3.1, ubuntu.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for testing.. Maybe I did not try without `whitespace-mode` after all, I will do some testing to check it now

Comment: @Tobias Seems like you are right. It really depends on `whitespace-mode`. Do you think this can be a bug in that mode?

Comment: See my partial answer... The final answer lies hidden in the c-sources of emacs. More precisely the source of `move-to-column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least a partial answer for now:

I am using emacs 24.3.1 under Ubuntu 13.04.
There, the effect is only reproducible with `whitespace-mode`. Thereby, `indent-tabs-mode` and also the buffer encoding as dos or unix do not really matter.

`whitespace-mode` fiddles with the `buffer-display-table`.

With a modified `buffer-display-table` one easily gets unexpected results for `move-to-column`.

The effect of `move-to-column` with `whitespace-mode` can already be reproduced without `whitespace-mode` if one executes the following code (use, e.g., <kbd>M-:</kbd>):

```lisp
(setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))
(aset buffer-display-table ?\n [?$ ?\n])
```

You can revert this effect by:

```lisp
(aset buffer-display-table ?\n nil)
```

You get a similarly unexpected effect of `move-to-column` if you change the number of displayed characters for any other text character. E.g:

With

```lisp
(aset buffer-display-table ?\§ [?\§ ?\$])
```

and the buffer content

§

you get the display

§$

If you call `(move-to-column 1 t)` point moves to the end of this displayed string even if this makes two displayed characters.

You can revert this setting by:

```lisp
(aset buffer-display-table ?\§ nil)
```

A further rather interesting setting is:

```lisp
(aset buffer-display-table ?\n [?1 ?2 ?3 ?\n])
```

With this setting the newline character is three displayed characters long (exclusively the line break).
One linebreak is shown as:

123

If the current point is at the beginning of that line the command `(move-to-column 3 t)` does not move point but returns 3.

Note, that this behaviour is consistent with the case of the normal setting

```lisp
(aset buffer-display-table ?\n nil)
```

If there are two consecutive linebreaks and point is positioned in between then `(move-to-column 0 t)` does place point before the linebreak even if there is no character on column 0.

Maybe, this is connected to the interpretation of point positions as being between characters. For an empty buffer one has `(point)` == `(point-min)` == `(point-max)`. This interpretation also gives `(point-max)` == `(1+ (buffer-size))` its meaning.

I cite here the description of `following-char` in the info-node `(elisp) Near Point`:

"Remember that point is always between characters, and the cursor
   normally appears over the character following point.  Therefore,
   the character returned by `following-char' is the character the
   cursor is over."

---

### Point positions between characters and `move-to-column`

(Note, the following is just my interpretation. It would be nice if someone who really knows the intentions in the features of `move-to-column` could acknowledge, deny, or correct this stuff.)

The following discussion illustrates the consequences of point positions **between** characters for `move-to-column`.
We denote the point positions by pos0, pos1,... and the characters with char1, char2,....
We use the denotation char1a, char1b, ... if the entry of a character char1 in `buffer-display-table` is a vector `[char1a char1b ...]` of length > 1. In the following we name such an character as ***compound character***.

Normal case (no compound characters):

pos0 char1 pos1 char2 pos2 nl

`(move-to-column 2 t)` means to position the point before the nlchar.

Case with a compound character char1 = [char1a char1b] in `buffer-display-table`:

pos0 char1a pos1 char1b pos2 nl

`move-to-column` respects the display size of the compound character but it cannot put point in the middle of it.
Point can only be placed at the boundaries of the compound character.

In this case `(move-to-column 1 t)` moves point to position pos2.

Now, let the new-line character be a composed character nl = [nla nlb].

pos0 char1 pos1 char2 pos2 nla pos3 nlb

Here, `(move-to-column 3 t)` arrives in the middle of the composed newline character.

Point is still on this line. So it does not make sense to put point behind nlb. Emacs cannot place point at pos3 since this is in the middle of a composed character. Thus, the only sensible way to position point is pos2.

Comment: Note, that I've added `(setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))` since this is required at least once for a buffer to be able to modify the `buffer-display-table`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! I will have a look at this.. Regarding your first comment: That `indent-tabs-mode` does not matter. To me it seems that it does matter. Turning it on `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)` apparently makes `(move-to-column pos t)` work as expected in `whitespace-mode`..

Comment: So is this a bug in `move-to-column` then? And how could I fix it?

Comment: AFAIK the behaviour of `move-to-column` is not specified in the documentation for the case that the newline character has a vector of length > 1 as entry in `buffer-display-table`. So, I would say that this is not a bug but an unspecified case. Nevertheless, emacs reacts sensible in such cases. I have added a section about "Point positions between characters and move-to-column" here. This illustrates the difficulties with the compound newline and the resolution emacs takes.

Comment: Reading this over quickly, and trying the recipes given in the question, I can at least confirm that what @Tobias says seems right to me. It appears to me that there is an Emacs bug here: `move-to-column` should always move to the right column, and it does not seem to do that in the OP example.  Please consider submitting a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the review. At first I also thought this could be a bug. But, now I think it is more like a dilemma. The problem only occurs with compound newline characters. If we end up in the middle of a compound newline then moving behind the compound means jumping to the next line. Also extending the line with spaces is not right since the display of the line has really the requested length. The emacs developers took the alternative to place point at the left boundary of the compound character in this special case. ∑: There are only bad choices and one has to pick one.

Comment: @Drew Nevertheless, maybe a bug report could point out the problem and the related dilemma.

Comment: I think a bug report is in order. That opens the question for more discussion and consideration by those responsible. To me, it is a bug for `move-to-column` to ***ever*** move to the wrong column.  A priori, I think it should be easy to test `bolp` or something in the code, to DTRT.